# ContentEditable component inside a react tab component does not work when the value is cleared

Tags: html, css, reactjs, contenteditable, react-tabs

I am trying to make the tab name editable.
For example: [image]

In the case of the image above, I want the "office" to be editable.

I am using the following packages
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable

https://reactcommunity.org/react-tabs/

The code looks as follows:

```
<Tab key={key}><ContentEditable
              html={temp} 
              disabled={false}       
              tagName='article'
            /></Tab>
```

The editing part works unit I clear out all the letters and then the tab collapses so I can't type anymore.

I also tried:

```
<Tab key={key}><p contentEditable="true">hello</p></Tab>
```

I even tried setting a fixed height and width to the p tag and the  component but that did not help

Basically it looks like 
[image]

As you can see the cursor is gone and I cannot type anymore.

Any suggestions would help. Thank you

Comment: try to give some contents when it is empty : `[contenteditable]:empty{content:'type in here'}` if you do not use a placeholder.

Comment: @G-Cyr OMG! it works!! Thank you!!!